# AWS Lambda error for connectorx library: No module named 'connectorx.connectorx

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm new to AWS Lambda service and I'm trying to upload a Python code that uses the "connectorx" library.

I'm aware that I need to create a layer to use an external library or uploading the library files inside a zip folder inside the lambda function. I tried both, but I'm still getting the same error:

```
"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'connectorx.connectorx'"
```

My ZIP file structure looks like the following:

```
my-deployment.zip
   -> connectorx
   -> connectorx-0.3.1.dist-info
   -> src
   -> lambda_function.py
```

where the folder "connectorx" and "connectorx-0.3.1.dist-info" comes from the pip install command as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html#python-package-dependencies)

I'm importing the library inside my code as follows:

```
import connectorx as cx
```

Could someone help me, please?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is due to incorrect zipping.

Follow the below steps exactly

- create your lambda function file
- install connectorx as shown below

```
pip install --target ./package connectorx
```

- copy your lambda function file to package directory
- Now run below commands to create the deployment package zip.

```
cd package
zip -r ../my-deployment-package.zip .
```

- Upload the deployment zip in lambda and don't forget to correctly point lambda_handler function in runtime settings.

Comment: hello @Msvsti, thank you for your comments.
The problem is that the commands above generates exactly the same path structure that I've mentioned on my question... Still don't work :(

Comment: @fernandofincatti how did you zip your deployment package? Using command line or manually using GUI?